# Decompiling MCP error (version 9.18) returns 'Decompile Failed'

Tags: minecraft

I have decided to take on MCP and have downloaded it, however, when running the decompile.bat, it returns an error.

(I'm running 32-bit Windows 10)

Here is what it returned:

> '"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java" -jar runtime\bin\fernflower.jar -din=1 -rbr=1 -dgs=1 -asc=1 -rsy=1 -iec=1 -jvn=1 -log=WARN "-e=jars\libraries\net/java/jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/lwjgl/lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl-platform-2.9.4-nightly-20150209-natives-windows.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/ibm/icu\icu4j-core-mojang\51.2\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\tv/twitch\twitch-external-platform\4.5\twitch-external-platform-4.5-natives-windows-32.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache/httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3.2\httpcore-4.3.2.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache/logging/log4j\log4j-api\2.0-beta9\log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache/commons\commons-lang3\3.3.2\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\net/java/jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\net/java/dev/jna\jna\3.4.0\jna-3.4.0.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\net/sf/jopt-simple\jopt-simple\4.6\jopt-simple-4.6.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/google/guava\guava\17.0\guava-17.0.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\oshi-project\oshi-core\1.1\oshi-core-1.1.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache/commons\commons-compress\1.8.1\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\net/java/dev/jna\platform\3.4.0\platform-3.4.0.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\codecjorbis-20101023.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\soundsystem-20120107.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/lwjgl/lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl_util-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.9\commons-codec-1.9.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache/httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.3\httpclient-4.3.3.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/lwjgl/lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/mojang\realms\1.7.39\realms-1.7.39.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/mojang\authlib\1.5.21\authlib-1.5.21.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/google/code/gson\gson\2.2.4\gson-2.2.4.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\tv/twitch\twitch\6.5\twitch-6.5.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/paulscode\codecwav\20101023\codecwav-20101023.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\tv/twitch\twitch-platform\6.5\twitch-platform-6.5-natives-windows-32.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\net/java/jinput\jinput-platform\2.0.5\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache/logging/log4j\log4j-core\2.0-beta9\log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\io/netty\netty-all\4.0.23.Final\netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar" temp/minecraft_ff_in.jar temp\src\minecraft' failed : 1
>   Decompile failed

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please make the following edits to your post: 1) format your code using 4 spaces rather than the back tick; 2) Please list your OS as part of your post rather than in your title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by the decompilation system running out of RAM.  I'm not *entirely* sure why it's happening, but it also was happening to me.

If you're using Minecraft Forge's ForgeGradle, [see this](https://github.com/MinecraftForge/ForgeGradle/issues/324#issuecomment-170273678).  You can either edit the gradle options file ( `.gradle/gradle.properties` in your user folder) and add `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2G` to it, or you can set the options variable to `-Xmx2G` (in a command prompt, run `set GRADLE_OPTS=-Xmx2G` and then `gradlew  setupDecompWorkspace`).

---

**However, given that you referenced `decompile.bat`, you probably are using MCP without Forge**. (Which is fine but forge does make mods easier/more compatible; you may want to consider doing this if you're making a more permanent mod rather than just messing about.) In this case, you can edit MCP's configuration to increase the given RAM.

In the MCP folder, open the `conf` folder and then open `mcp.cfg` with a text editor of your choice.  Then, find this line (near the bottom)

```
CmdFernflower = %s -jar %s -din=1 -rbr=0 -dgs=1 -asc=1 -log=WARN {indir} {outdir}
```

and replace it with this:

```
CmdFernflower = %s -Xmx2G -jar %s -din=1 -rbr=0 -dgs=1 -asc=1 -log=WARN {indir} {outdir}
```

(You may need to change other lines also adding `-Xmx2G` before `-jar` but it doesn't *seem* to be needed from my experience).

This will run the decompiler with additional RAM.

---

Alternatively, if you don't want to mess around with the MCP configuration, MCP910 doesn't seem to have this issue.  It works with 1.8.0 instead of 1.8.8, but should still do everything you want.

Comment: You now what I knew that I needed to change the RAM settings yet I had no idea where to change it!

Comment: This works. Thank you. 
But damn, it consumed 1.6 gigs

Answer (score 0):

I know, this answer comes very late, but you should install the 64-bit Version of Java. With the 32-Bit Version, it doesn't work...
I don't know if you can install this on your 32-Bit System, but you can try it. On my 86-Bit System (Windows 8) it works!