# MCP940 Decompile.bat errors

Tags: java, windows, jar, minecraft

I Downloaded mcp940 a few weeks ago and have been having massive problems, first when I tried using the newest version (1.12) it gave me an error:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\bin\java" -jar runtime\bin\fernflower.jar -din=1 -rbr=1 -dgs=1 -asc=1 -rsy=1 -iec=1 -jvn=1 -log=TRACE "-e=jars\libraries\net/java/jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/ibm/icu\icu4j-core-mojang\51.2\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache/httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3.2\httpcore-4.3.2.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache/logging/log4j\log4j-api\2.8.1\log4j-api-2.8.1.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache/commons\commons-lang3\3.5\commons-lang3-3.5.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\net/java/dev/jna\jna\4.4.0\jna-4.4.0.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/lwjgl/lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl-platform-2.9.4-nightly-20150209-natives-windows.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\net/sf/jopt-simple\jopt-simple\5.0.3\jopt-simple-5.0.3.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/mojang\text2speech\1.10.3\text2speech-1.10.3.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/google/guava\guava\21.0\guava-21.0.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\oshi-project\oshi-core\1.1\oshi-core-1.1.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache/httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.3\httpclient-4.3.3.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache/commons\commons-compress\1.8.1\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/mojang\text2speech\1.10.3\text2speech-1.10.3-natives-windows.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\it/unimi/dsi\fastutil\7.1.0\fastutil-7.1.0.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\net/java/dev/jna\platform\3.4.0\platform-3.4.0.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\codecjorbis-20101023.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\soundsystem-20120107.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/lwjgl/lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl_util-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.10\commons-codec-1.10.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\net/java/jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/mojang\patchy\1.1\patchy-1.1.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/lwjgl/lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.5\commons-io-2.5.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/mojang\realms\1.10.17\realms-1.10.17.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/mojang\authlib\1.5.25\authlib-1.5.25.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/google/code/gson\gson\2.8.0\gson-2.8.0.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\net/java/jinput\jinput-platform\2.0.5\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/paulscode\codecwav\20101023\codecwav-20101023.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache/logging/log4j\log4j-core\2.8.1\log4j-core-2.8.1.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\io/netty\netty-all\4.1.9.Final\netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar" temp/minecraft_ff_in.jar temp\src\minecraft' failed : 1 Decompile failed`

I've been searching around and have had no luck, first I found someone saying I should add `-Xmx2G` to the beginning of a string in  `mcp.cfg` Here it is before and after

`CmdFernflower = %s -jar %s -din=1 -rbr=1 -dgs=1 -asc=1 -rsy=1 -iec=1 -jvn=1 -log=TRACE {extra} {indir} {outdir}`

`CmdFernflower = %s -Xmx2G -jar %s -din=1 -rbr=1 -dgs=1 -asc=1 -rsy=1 -iec=1 -jvn=1 -log=TRACE {extra} {indir} {outdir}`

after I added that it gave me another error:

`'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\bin\java" -Xmx2G -jar runtime\bin\fernflower.jar -din=1 -rbr=1 -dgs=1 -asc=1 -rsy=1 -iec=1 -jvn=1 -log=TRACE "-e=jars\libraries\net/java/jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/ibm/icu\icu4j-core-mojang\51.2\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache/httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3.2\httpcore-4.3.2.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache/logging/log4j\log4j-api\2.8.1\log4j-api-2.8.1.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache/commons\commons-lang3\3.5\commons-lang3-3.5.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\net/java/dev/jna\jna\4.4.0\jna-4.4.0.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/lwjgl/lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl-platform-2.9.4-nightly-20150209-natives-windows.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\net/sf/jopt-simple\jopt-simple\5.0.3\jopt-simple-5.0.3.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/mojang\text2speech\1.10.3\text2speech-1.10.3.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/google/guava\guava\21.0\guava-21.0.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\oshi-project\oshi-core\1.1\oshi-core-1.1.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache/httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.3\httpclient-4.3.3.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache/commons\commons-compress\1.8.1\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/mojang\text2speech\1.10.3\text2speech-1.10.3-natives-windows.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\it/unimi/dsi\fastutil\7.1.0\fastutil-7.1.0.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\net/java/dev/jna\platform\3.4.0\platform-3.4.0.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\codecjorbis-20101023.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\soundsystem-20120107.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/lwjgl/lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl_util-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.10\commons-codec-1.10.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\net/java/jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/mojang\patchy\1.1\patchy-1.1.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/lwjgl/lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.5\commons-io-2.5.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/mojang\realms\1.10.17\realms-1.10.17.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/mojang\authlib\1.5.25\authlib-1.5.25.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/google/code/gson\gson\2.8.0\gson-2.8.0.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\net/java/jinput\jinput-platform\2.0.5\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/paulscode\codecwav\20101023\codecwav-20101023.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache/logging/log4j\log4j-core\2.8.1\log4j-core-2.8.1.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\io/netty\netty-all\4.1.9.Final\netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar" temp/minecraft_ff_in.jar temp\src\minecraft' failed : 1 Decompile failed`

It's very similar to the old error and not the same as the first error I got when adding `-Xmx2G`

Strangely enough, I don't get this error in 1.7.10 (mcp908) and can edit the game fine, I was also able to go in the Wayback machine and use 1.8 (mcp910?)

Comment: We need the actual error, not just the command line and "decompile failed".

Comment: ``-Xmx2G`` is a flag that tells Java that it can use 2 Gigabytes of your computer's memory, it shouldn't normally affect MCP's ability to decompile. I'm aware MCP doesn't typically offer much in the way of error reports, but linking [the source that recommended that course of action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34969224/decompiling-mcp-error-version-9-18-returns-decompile-failed) might help others to help you. Based on that person's answer, you might try upping the -Xmx flag to 4G or even 6G, based on your system's available memory.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Wdym we need the actual error? Do you want the logs?

Comment: Sure, post the logs.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1OM38EXho2fAVuuCaKvQTphRXBIVDQ8v9?usp=sharing

Comment: Also @AegisHexad I upped it to 6G's and nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is apparent from the end of mcp.log:

```
17:30:05 - Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
17:30:05 - Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
17:30:05 - Invalid initial heap size: -Xms6000M
17:30:05 - The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
17:30:05 - '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\bin\java" -Xms6000M
```

32-bit programs can't use 6GB of RAM. The `(x86)` in your path indicates that you're running 32-bit Java even though you're on a 64-bit system. Uninstall it and replace it with 64-bit Java.

Comment: Thank You! I feel so stupid because I tried everything but this! It's strange though, I Redownloaded java after uninstalling and it was 32-bit, I had to manually install 64-bit Java.

Comment: Also, do you know how the dev's at MCP deobfuscate Minecraft versions? I was wondering how I could deobfuscate 1.15.2

Comment: @IDefeat Basically, they look at the functions, figure out what they do, and make up a meaningful name for them.

Comment: nice! I watched a video on how to deobfuscate 1.15.2 and it worked, but I don't know how to put it into eclipse to edit :/ Here's the video link: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2JVDZzhOFFY)