# What causes this error decompiling Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

I have a big problem with the `decompile.bat` in the modcoderpack 918 with minecraft 1.8.8.
My Java version is 1.8.0_271-b09.

```
Decompiling
'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_271\bin\java" -jar runtime\bin\fernflower.jar -din=1 -rbr=1 -dgs=1 -asc=1 -rsy=1 -iec=1 -jvn=1 -log=WARN "-e=jars\libraries\net/java/jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/lwjgl/lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl-platform-2.9.4-nightly-20150209-natives-windows.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/ibm/icu\icu4j-core-mojang\51.2\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\tv/twitch\twitch-external-platform\4.5\twitch-external-platform-4.5-natives-windows-64.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache/httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3.2\httpcore-4.3.2.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache/logging/log4j\log4j-api\2.0-beta9\log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache/commons\commons-lang3\3.3.2\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\net/java/dev/jna\jna\3.4.0\jna-3.4.0.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\net/sf/jopt-simple\jopt-simple\4.6\jopt-simple-4.6.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/google/guava\guava\17.0\guava-17.0.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\oshi-project\oshi-core\1.1\oshi-core-1.1.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache/httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.3\httpclient-4.3.3.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache/commons\commons-compress\1.8.1\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\net/java/dev/jna\platform\3.4.0\platform-3.4.0.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\codecjorbis-20101023.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\soundsystem-20120107.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/lwjgl/lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl_util-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.9\commons-codec-1.9.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\net/java/jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/lwjgl/lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/mojang\realms\1.7.39\realms-1.7.39.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/mojang\authlib\1.5.21\authlib-1.5.21.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/google/code/gson\gson\2.2.4\gson-2.2.4.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/mojang\netty\1.6\netty-1.6.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\tv/twitch\twitch\6.5\twitch-6.5.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/paulscode\codecwav\20101023\codecwav-20101023.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\tv/twitch\twitch-platform\6.5\twitch-platform-6.5-natives-windows-64.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\net/java/jinput\jinput-platform\2.0.5\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache/logging/log4j\log4j-core\2.0-beta9\log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\io/netty\netty-all\4.0.23.Final\netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar" temp/minecraft_ff_in.jar temp\src\minecraft' failed : 1
Decompile failed
```

I don't know what I have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34969224/decompiling-mcp-error-version-9-18-returns-decompile-failed) answer your question? The issue could possibly be that MCP 918 is running out of RAM (memory).

> In the MCP folder, open the conf folder and then open mcp.cfg with a text editor of your choice. Then, find this line (near the bottom)

`CmdFernflower = %s -jar %s -din=1 -rbr=0 -dgs=1 -asc=1 -log=WARN {indir} {outdir}`

> and replace it with this:

`CmdFernflower = %s -Xmx2G -jar %s -din=1 -rbr=0 -dgs=1 -asc=1 -log=WARN {indir} {outdir}`

Hopefully this fixes your issue.